# Server side marker clustering PHP & Mongodb

Tags: javascript, php, mongodb, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have implemented a server side marker clustering by following what says in this link
http://www.appelsiini.net/2008/introduction-to-marker-clustering-with-google-maps

This works perfect for markers less than 5,000. But when my markers increased to 17,000
it causes all the memory to exhaust as there are very big loops running.
I am using mongodb for storing all my records with lat n long,

Can i make use of the mongodb's spatial query feature for clustering ?

Some how i want server load to be very less calculating the clusters each time user drags the map,
So far i'm doing the clustering as follows

```
while (count($markers)) {
        $marker  = array_pop($markers);
        $cluster = array();
        /* Compare against all markers which are left. */
        foreach ($markers as $key => $target) {
            $pixels = $this->pixelDistance($marker['lat'], $marker['long'],
                                    $target['lat'], $target['long'],
                                    $zoom);
        if ($distance > $pixels && $zoom < 18) {
           unset($markers[$key]);
                $cluster[] = $target;
        }
       if (count($cluster) > 0) {
                $cluster[] = $marker;
                $clustered[] = $cluster;
            } else {
                $clustered[] = $marker;
            }
        }
    $newarray = array();
    foreach($clustered as $key => $cluster) {
        $centroid = array('lat' => 0, 'long' => 0, 'count' => 0);
        if(isset($cluster[0]) && is_array($cluster[0])){            
            foreach($cluster as $marker) {    
            //echo "{$key} =>"; printArray($marker);
                //if($key != 10){
                    $centroid['lat'] += $marker['lat']; // Sum up the Lats
                    $centroid['long'] += $marker['long']; // Sum up the Lngs
                    $centroid['count']++;
                //}
            }
            //if($centroid['count'] != 0){
                $centroid['lat'] /= $centroid['count']; // Average Lat
                $centroid['long'] /= $centroid['count']; // Average Lng
                $clustered[$key] = $centroid; // Overwrite the cluster with the single point.
            //}
        }
    }
    return $clustered;
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can use a bounding box to narrow the search.  A longitude is 111 km: http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longitude. The tile is calculated with 3 variables x,y,z. It uses a 2 dimensional  grid with the x and y axis and the zoom level z.  Read here:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb259689.aspx. Basically you need to convert the lat-lng pair to pixel coordinates. Then you can get the tile-number from it. The maximum pixel is a power of 2 number. Hence the big number at maximum zoom level. Because you insist from the bing tiling system:

> To optimize the indexing and storage of tiles, the two-dimensional tile XY coordinates are combined into one-dimensional strings called quadtree keys, or “quadkeys” for short. Each quadkey uniquely identifies a single tile at a particular level of detail, and it can be used as an key in common database B-tree indexes. To convert tile coordinates into a quadkey, the bits of the Y and X coordinates are interleaved, and the result is interpreted as a base-4 number (with leading zeros maintained) and converted into a string. For instance, given tile XY coordinates of (3, 5) at level 3, the quadkey is determined as follows:
>
> tileX = 3 = 011 2
>
> tileY = 5 = 101 2
>
> quadkey = 100111 2 = 213 4 = “213”
>
> Quadkeys have several interesting properties. First, the length of a quadkey (the number 
>   of   digits) equals the level of detail of the corresponding tile. Second, the quadkey of > any  tile starts with the quadkey of its parent tile (the containing tile at the 
>   previous level).

It's very similar to a quadtree or r-tree and it should be a good exercise for the reader but you already have the bing tile code.

Comment: http://www.soak.co.uk/blog/technical/server-side-map-marker-clustering/
This link seems useful, but how to implement the tiles on google maps at different zoom levels!

Comment: I updated my answer. Read here:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb259689.aspx.

Comment: Please see this site, http://www.middlesexcountyhomesearcher.com/results-map
How they are having that overlays of different sizes at different regions of the map?

Comment: You need the bing tile system especially about generating a quadkey:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb259689.aspx. It's a good practice, too.